Dangerously Set Inner HTML is not displaying the HTML change
So I am making a gemini clone and I have set up the api and I am getting the response on the console but when when its not updating in the html
I tried looking in the gemini api logic and i am calling the result like this
const result = await chatSession.sendMessage(prompt);
    console.log(result.response.text());
    return response.text();
  }
  
   export default run;

This is how i am using it  
          <div className="result-data">
          <img src={assets.gemini_icon} alt="" />
          <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:resultData}}></p>
        </div>
And s this is my onSent function
const onSent = async(prompt) => {

        setResultData("")
        setLoading(true)
        setShowResult(true)
        setRecentPrompt(input)
        const response = await run(input)
        setResultData = (response)
        setLoading = (false)
        setInput = ("")
    }


the code you shared is quite odd.. I mean things like setResultData = (response) or setLoading = (false) ,,, or having a prompt argument for the onSent function but then using input. I think you should really put more efforts before coming back here and ask again

first the basic mistake according to me is that setting the state should be done like this setResultData(response), not like this setResultData = (response).
const onSent = async (prompt) => {
        setResultData(""); // Clear previous result data
        setLoading(true); // Set loading to true
        setShowResult(true); // Show the result container
        setRecentPrompt(prompt); // Update the recent prompt
        enter code here
        try {
            const response = await run(prompt);
            console.log(response)l;
            console.log(response.value
            setResultData(response); // Update the result data
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error:", error); // Handle error if any
        } finally {
            setLoading(false); // Set loading to false
            setInput(""); // Clear the input
        }
    };

make sure that your run function is returning the response correctly
const run = async (prompt) => {
    const result = await chatSession.sendMessage(prompt);
    const text = await result.response.text();
    console.log(text);
    return text;
};

export default run;

